# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session with GORM (Grails)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

First: I am aware that there are a bunch of similar questions been asked already; However, I am still struggling to. find a solution to this issue.

In our app, we have a workspace membership that is simply a link between a user and a workspace. The workspace membership object is softdeletable. In some cases, the user needs to add a member that was originally deleted from the workspace. In that case, we are trying to find the deleted membership by user and workspace and "undelete" it. Here is the function that should do it (including the creation of new membership if one does not exist):

```
WorkspaceMembership addUserToWorkspace(
            User user,
            Workspace workspace,
            User addedBy,
            WorkspaceMembershipLevel membershipLevel = WorkspaceMembershipLevel.Standard
    ) {
        Optional<WorkspaceMembership> existingMembership =
                workspaceRepositoryService.getWorkspaceMembership(user, workspace, true)

        existingMembership.map { membership ->
            if (membership.deletedAt) {
                // undelete the membership
                membership.deletedAt = null
                membership.deletedBy = null
                membership.updatedBy = addedBy
                membership.lastUpdated = new Date()
                membership.save()
            }

            membership
        }.orElse(
                new WorkspaceMembership(
                        user: user,
                        workspace: workspace,
                        membershipLevel: membershipLevel,
                        createdBy: addedBy,
                        dateCreated: new Date()
                ).save()
        )
    }
```

The code is pretty simple and self-explanatory. But I am getting the following error when I am trying to undelete the object:

> message:A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [priz.workspace.WorkspaceMembership#priz.workspace.WorkspaceMembership : (unsaved)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [priz.workspace.WorkspaceMembership#priz.workspace.WorkspaceMembership : (unsaved)]]

Based on a bunch of posts I figured that merging the sessions should help:

```
if (membership.deletedAt) {
                // undelete the membership
                membership.deletedAt = null
                membership.deletedBy = null
                membership.updatedBy = addedBy
                membership.lastUpdated = new Date()
                membership = membership.merge()
            }

            membership
```

This did not help.

Also, I thought, since the error complains about the workspace object, I decided to try and merge `workspace` and `user` too (even though it does not make much sense).

```
if (membership.deletedAt) {
                // undelete the membership
                membership.deletedAt = null
                membership.deletedBy = null
                membership.updatedBy = addedBy
                membership.lastUpdated = new Date()
                membership.workspace = membership.workspace.merge()
                membership.user = membership.user.merge()
                return membership.merge()
            } else {
                membership
            }
```

Same result...

What are the options here?

Comment: Are any of the entities retrieved from the database in a different Hibernate session?

Comment: There is only once session, if I understand correctly

Comment: "There is only once session, if I understand correctly" - Why would you call `membership.user.merge()` and `membership.workspace.merge()`?

Comment: I was trying, because the error was complaining about it